# AWS SNS HTTP subscription is not calling endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, localstack

I have deployed AWS SNS using [Localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) in my dev machine and now I'm trying to consume messages I'm emitting from `awslocal` CLI (basically it's a `aws` against my local Localstack infra)

First, I have created a topic:

```
$ awslocal sns create-topic --name my-topic
```

Then, I've created a HTTP subcription against `http://localhost:8080/sns/publish`:

```
$ awslocal sns subscribe --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:my-topic" --protocol http --notification-endpoint http://localhost:8080/sns/publish
```

I have a server running at `localhost` in port `8080` with a POST `/sns/publish` endpoint. It is supposed to be called in order to confirm the subscription. But it's never called.

I have some clues. I have deployed Localstack using Docker. After checking the container logs, I have seen this error:

```
2018-07-02T10:20:03:INFO:werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2018 10:20:03] "POST /sns/publish HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

HTTP ERROR 405 corresponds to Method Not Allowed error so maybe it's trying to call a container endpoint instead of my host machine's endpoint.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was a IP resolving problem beacuse of Docker networking.

I've created a subnet:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 mynet
```

And subscribe SNS against `192.168.9.1` instead of `localhost`:

```
$ awslocal sns subscribe --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:my-topic" --protocol http --notification-endpoint http://192.168.0.1:8080/sns/publish
```

Done!

Comment: Not working. Getting error

2020-10-13T10:13:22:INFO:localstack.services.sns.sns_listener: Received error on sending SNS message, putting to DLQ (if configured): MyHTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9000): Max retries exceeded with url: /sns/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9c1fdc0df0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: On Mac, I was able to make it work by setting the reserved host.docker.internal as the notification endpoint. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds

Comment: @David - I seem to be stuck on the same thing. Which environment variable of localstack did you point to host.docker.internal? And what's the syntax? I tried doing this `HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=host.docker.internal` but I still get the same error